# Type script: Type '(close: any) => Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, popup

I'm adding a popup in my type script and i just can't solve this issue

```
Type '(close: any) => Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
```

```
<Popup
        trigger={
          <button
            className="fixed bottom-10 right-10 h-20 w-20 justify-center flex items-center bg-blue-200 rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-500"
            onClick={() => handleResult()}
          >
            <Submit />
          </button>
        }
        closeOnDocumentClick={false}
        modal
      >
        {(close) => (
          <div className="fixed right-1/2 top-1/2 h-32 border-2 w-64 bg-slate-300 border-slate-400 flex items-center justify-center rounded-xl">
            <button
              className="absolute right-1 top-1 rounded-xl border-2 h-7 w-10 bg-red-500  "
              onClick={() => close()}
            >
              <p> x</p>
            </button>
            <Link
              to="/result"
              state={{ diagnosisResult: result, remark: remark }}
              className={textStyle}
            >
              View Result Here!!!
            </Link>
          </div>
        )}
      </Popup>
```

i've tried making it `(close : ()=>void)` but it is still not working, all tried different solution i can find but all are not working(i mean the code is working right its just that error still pop up) so i can't run it on vercel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside <Popup>, You are just declaring you arrow function (*(close : any) => Element* ) without calling it. I just wrap your function with parentheses and call you function:

```
((param : any) => {doThing()})() // <- () at this end to call your function
```

Your edited code

```
     <Popup
        trigger={
          <button
            className="fixed bottom-10 right-10 h-20 w-20 justify-center flex items-center bg-blue-200 rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-500"
            onClick={() => handleResult()}
          >
            <Submit />
          </button>
        }
        closeOnDocumentClick={false}
        modal
      >
        {((close) => (
          <div className="fixed right-1/2 top-1/2 h-32 border-2 w-64 bg-slate-300 border-slate-400 flex items-center justify-center rounded-xl">
           {//...}
          </div>
        ))()}
      </Popup>
```

Comment: you mean like this?? but the "x" button is not working
`{((close) => (
  <div className="">
    <button
      className=""
      onClick={() => close()}
    >
      <p>x</p>
    </button>
    <Link
      to="/result"
      state={{ diagnosisResult: result, remark: remark }}
      className={textStyle}
    >
      View Result Here!!!
    </Link>
  </div>
))(close)}`

Comment: I don't thing this problem is link to your initial problem. Did you solve it ?